# Can you use a CloudFront dist for two record sets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have created a Web CloudFront Distribution. I have two Record Sets
1. First Record Set is for my domain example.com, A record with Alias pointing to the CDN
2. Second Record Set for my domain www.example.com, A record but I do NOT see the CDN in the drop-down. Is this a known limitation?

Comment: The only limitation is if you have a valid SSL cert, covering all the domains and if you list the alternative cnames on the distribution; is the second subdomain/cname listed on the alternative cnames for the CloudFront distribution?

Comment: I added a cert using ACM, I added both domains (example.com and www.example.com) and the status is "Issues". What is weird is that when I try creating a Web Dist and add both example.com and www.example.com under CNAMEs, the cert created before does NOT show up under Custom SSL certs radio button.

Comment: Is the ACM cert in us-east-1? If not, create the ACM cert in us-east-1.

Answer (score 0):

If you give CNAME while creation of Cloudfront then it will show you while 
creation of record set.

Do this :

1. Modify existing CloudFront
2. Add CNAME using comma separate like `example.com,www.example.com`
3. Save it, it will take some time to reflect in record set dropdown
4. Then create record set will show same CloudFront for selection.